# Call Apache Cordova CLI from Java

Tags: java, macos, cordova, process, cmd

I want the Apache Cordova CLI being called by a Java Process but unfortunatly the Java Process doesn't wait until it is finished.

This is, how i call it:

```
StringBuffer sb = null;
String cmd = "cd /location/generated && cordova create MyNewApp"

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've seen many solutions, that say "waitFor()" will do the trick but unfortunatly not for me. I've already tried to always read and compare the last line of code generated by the cordova cmd and finish afterwards, but this is not a good approach. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it:
Cmd looks like this "cordova create /path/to/generated/app/ Hello World"

Be aware, the path has to exist before the cmd is beeing called